# Move Linux installation to another machine (UEFI)

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, bios, migration

I'm using a UEFI installation of Ubuntu 21.04. I have to change my laptop to another one with very similar configuration. I do not want to reinstall the OS because it may be time consuming to set everything up even if I copy the home dir. Back in the BIOS/MBR times I used to just make an image of the HDD or move the HDD physically to another machine and it was fine. I wonder if this is possible with UEFI and if yes, would it be necessary to do some additional actions?

Comment: Yes, but you posted 46 minutes ago and could have done a new install in that time. And probably copied /home with all your configuration files from your normal backup to new install. Only a bit time consuming is reinstalling all the apps your have added from the list you include as part of backup, if you have slower internet & lots of added apps. If UEFI you have to recreate the UEFI entry in new systems. Often easier just to totally reinstall grub with Boot-Repair, but all you really need is efibootmgr. See `man efibootmgr`

Comment: Thanks! I will try efibootmgr.
New install would take longer for me, because I have lot of settings outside home dir(cgroups etc).

Comment: Some more examples of efibootmgr. See VI. https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win Some prefer GUI.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ Boot-Repair's main fix is reinstall of grub. Grub uses efibootmgr to create new UEFI entry, But grub reinstall will overwrite any grub changes you made.